# GWT CompositeEditor - Dynamically switched editor not being added to chain properly

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, gwt-editors

I've got a value type `Commission` that's part of a larger editor graph:

```
public class Commission implements Serializable
{
    private CommissionType commissionType; // enum
    private Money value; // custom type, backed by BigDecimal
    private Integer multiplier;
    private Integer contractMonths;

    // ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is to initially only show the dropdown for the `commissionType` enum, and then select an appropriate sub-editor to edit the rest of the fields based on the value selected:

[image: CommissionType.UNIT_RATE selected]

[image: CommissionType.STANDING_CHARGE selected]

I have previously implemented multiple subtype editors ([see question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346308/how-to-implement-gwt-editors-for-subclasses-of-a-type)) using an `AbstractSubTypeEditor` but this case is slightly different as I am not editing subclasses, they all edit the same basic `Commission` type, and for some reason the same method does not seem to work with multiple editors that edit the same concrete type.

I currently have two sub-editors (both implement `Editor<Commission>` and `IsWidget` via a custom interface `IsCommissionEditorWidget`) but they have different sub-editors themselves, as the `Money` can be in either pence or pounds, and the multiplier can represent days or months, among other changes.

### CommissionEditor

I have looked at the similar problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043760/using-gwt-editors-with-a-complex-usecase) and tried to create a `CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, Editor<Commission>>`.

This is what I've got so far (note the commented out parts are the hacked way of getting the functionality I want, by implementing `LeafValueEditor<Commission>` and manually calling `setValue()` and `getValue()` on `amount`, `multiplier` and `contractMonths`):

```
public class CommissionEditor extends Composite implements CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, Editor<Commission>>, //LeafValueEditor<Commission>
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, CommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    CommissionTypeEditor commissionType;

    @UiField
    Panel subEditorPanel;

    private EditorChain<Commission, Editor<Commission>> chain;
    private IsCommissionEditorWidget subEditor = null;
    private Commission value = new Commission();

    public CommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        commissionType.box.addValueChangeHandler(event -> setValue(new Commission(event.getValue())));
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Commission value)
    {
        Log.warn("CommissionEditor -> setValue(): value is " + value);

        chain.detach(subEditor);

        commissionType.setValue(value.getCommissionType());

        if(value.getCommissionType() != null)
        {
            switch(value.getCommissionType())
            {
                case UNIT_RATE:
                    Log.info("UNIT_RATE");
                    subEditor = new UnitRateCommissionEditor();
                    break;
                case STANDING_CHARGE:
                    Log.info("STANDING_CHARGE");
                    subEditor = new StandingChargeCommissionEditor();
                    break;
                case PER_MWH:
                    Log.info("PER_MWH");
                    // TODO
                    break;
                case SINGLE_PAYMENT:
                    Log.info("SINGLE_PAYMENT");
                    // TODO
                    break;
            }

            this.value = value;
            subEditorPanel.clear();
//            subEditor.setValue(value);
            subEditorPanel.add(subEditor);
            chain.attach(value, subEditor);
        }

    }

//    @Override
//    public Commission getValue()
//    {
//        if(subEditor != null)
//        {
//            return subEditor.getValue();
//        }
//        else
//        {
//        return value;
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    {
        this.value = chain.getValue(subEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEditorChain(EditorChain<Commission, Editor<Commission>> chain)
    {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public Editor<Commission> createEditorForTraversal()
    {
        return subEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPathElement(Editor<Commission> commissionEditor)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... strings)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<Commission> editorDelegate)
    {

    }

}
```

This is the `IsCommissionEditorWidget` interface that defines the contract of each sub-editor also being able to be added to a panel:

```
public interface IsCommissionEditorWidget extends Editor<Commission>, IsWidget
{

}
```

#### UnitRateCommissionEditor

When the user selects `CommissionType.UNIT_RATE`, I want to add this to the editor chain to apply to the 3 remaining fields:

```
public class UnitRateCommissionEditor extends Composite implements IsCommissionEditorWidget
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, UnitRateCommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    MoneyPenceBox amount;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox multiplier;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox contractMonths;

    public UnitRateCommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

//    @Override
//    public void setValue(Commission commission)
//    {
//        amount.setValue(commission.getAmount());
//        multiplier.setValue(commission.getMultiplier());
//        contractMonths.setValue(commission.getContractMonths());
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public Commission getValue()
//    {
//        return new Commission(CommissionType.UNIT_RATE, amount.getValue(), multiplier.getValue(), contractMonths.getValue());
//    }
}
```

#### StandingChargeCommissionEditor

When `CommissionType.STANDING_CHARGE` is selected I want this one (The UiBinders are also a bit different, but the main difference is the `MoneyPoundsBox` instead of the `MoneyPenceBox`):

```
public class StandingChargeCommissionEditor extends Composite implements IsCommissionEditorWidget
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, StandingChargeCommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    MoneyPoundsBox amount;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox multiplier;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox contractMonths;

    public StandingChargeCommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

//    @Override
//    public void setValue(Commission commission)
//    {
//        amount.setValue(commission.getAmount());
//        multiplier.setValue(commission.getMultiplier());
//        contractMonths.setValue(commission.getContractMonths());
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    public Commission getValue()
//    {
//        return new Commission(CommissionType.STANDING_CHARGE, amount.getValue(), multiplier.getValue(), contractMonths.getValue());
//    }
}
```

**Currently the `flush()` of the parent type (the type being edited that contains the `Commission`) returns a Commission with an undefined `amount`, `multiplier` and `contractMonths`. The only way I can get those values to be passed in and out is to manually code it in (the commented code).**

- Is my sub-editor being attached to the `EditorChain` correctly?

---

## Edit 1: Solution Proposed

I decided to create a new intermediate class that would wrap each subtype commission separately, [using `AbstractSubTypeEditor` like I did in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346308/how-to-implement-gwt-editors-for-subclasses-of-a-type/13358890#13358890).

### CommissionEditor

Still a `CompositeEditor`, but it only ever has *one or zero sub-editors*, which will only ever be a `CommissionSubtypeEditor`:

```
public class CommissionEditor extends Composite implements CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, CommissionSubtypeEditor>, LeafValueEditor<Commission>
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, CommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    @Ignore
    CommissionTypeEditor commissionType;

    @UiField
    Panel subEditorPanel;

    private EditorChain<Commission, CommissionSubtypeEditor> chain;

    @Ignore
    @Path("")
    CommissionSubtypeEditor subEditor = new CommissionSubtypeEditor();

    private Commission value;

    public CommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));

        commissionType.box.addValueChangeHandler(event -> setValue(new Commission(event.getValue())));
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Commission value)
    {
        Log.warn("CommissionEditor -> setValue(): value is " + value);

        commissionType.setValue(value.getCommissionType());

        if(value.getCommissionType() != null)
        {
            this.value = value;
            subEditorPanel.clear();
            subEditorPanel.add(subEditor);
            chain.attach(value, subEditor);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Commission getValue()
    {
        Log.info("CommissionEditor -> getValue: " + value);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    {
        chain.getValue(subEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEditorChain(EditorChain<Commission, CommissionSubtypeEditor> chain)
    {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    @Override
    public CommissionSubtypeEditor createEditorForTraversal()
    {
        return subEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPathElement(CommissionSubtypeEditor commissionEditor)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... strings)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<Commission> editorDelegate)
    {

    }

}
```

### AbstractSubTypeEditor

Credit goes to [Florent Bayle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1820501/florent-bayle) for this class. I didn't think I could use it without the subtypes being polymorphic but it seems to work great. Essentially allows wrapping of sub-editors as will be show in `CommissionSubtypeEditor` next.

```
public abstract class AbstractSubTypeEditor<T, C extends T, E extends Editor<C>> implements CompositeEditor<T, C, E>, LeafValueEditor<T>
{
    private EditorChain<C, E> chain;
    private T currentValue;
    private final E subEditor;

    public AbstractSubTypeEditor(E subEditor)
    {
        this.subEditor = subEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public E createEditorForTraversal()
    {
        return subEditor;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    {
        currentValue = chain.getValue(subEditor);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPathElement(E subEditor)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue()
    {
        return currentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertyChange(String... paths)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void setDelegate(EditorDelegate<T> delegate)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void setEditorChain(EditorChain<C, E> chain)
    {
        this.chain = chain;
    }

    public void setValue(T value, boolean instanceOf)
    {
        if(currentValue != null && value == null)
        {
            chain.detach(subEditor);
        }
        currentValue = value;
        if(value != null && instanceOf)
        {
            chain.attach((C) value, subEditor);
        }
    }
}
```

### CommissionSubtypeEditor

```
public class CommissionSubtypeEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Commission>
{

    interface Binder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, CommissionSubtypeEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    Panel subEditorPanel;

    @Ignore
    final UnitRateCommissionEditor unitRateCommissionEditor = new UnitRateCommissionEditor();

    @Path("")
    final AbstractSubTypeEditor<Commission, Commission, UnitRateCommissionEditor> unitRateWrapper = new AbstractSubTypeEditor<Commission, Commission,
            UnitRateCommissionEditor>(unitRateCommissionEditor)
    {
        @Override
        public void setValue(Commission value)
        {
            if(value.getCommissionType() == CommissionType.UNIT_RATE)
            {
                Log.info("unitRateWrapper setValue");
                setValue(value, true);

                subEditorPanel.clear();
                subEditorPanel.add(unitRateCommissionEditor);

            }
        }
    };

    @Ignore
    final StandingChargeCommissionEditor standingChargeCommissionEditor = new StandingChargeCommissionEditor();

    @Path("")
    final AbstractSubTypeEditor<Commission, Commission, StandingChargeCommissionEditor> standingChargeWrapper = new AbstractSubTypeEditor<Commission,
            Commission, StandingChargeCommissionEditor>(standingChargeCommissionEditor)
    {
        @Override
        public void setValue(Commission value)
        {
            if(value.getCommissionType() == CommissionType.STANDING_CHARGE)
            {
                Log.info("standingChargeWrapper setValue");
                setValue(value, true);

                subEditorPanel.clear();
                subEditorPanel.add(standingChargeCommissionEditor);

            }
        }
    };

    public CommissionSubtypeEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

### UnitRateCommissionEditor and StandingChargeCommissionEditor

Both simple and implement `Editor<Commission>`:

```
public class UnitRateCommissionEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Commission>
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, UnitRateCommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    MoneyPenceBox amount;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox multiplier;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox contractMonths;

    public UnitRateCommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

almost there...

```
public class StandingChargeCommissionEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Commission>
{
    interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, StandingChargeCommissionEditor>
    {
    }

    private static Binder uiBinder = GWT.create(Binder.class);

    @UiField
    MoneyPoundsBox amount;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox multiplier;

    @UiField
    IntegerBox contractMonths;

    public StandingChargeCommissionEditor()
    {
        initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
    }

}
```

This does work and is similar to something I tried very early on when I had the `AbstractSubtypeEditor`s in the `CompositeEditor` itself. The problem there I believe was that the editor could not call `setValue()` on itself. Am I right?

#### Comments, criticisms and advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you initializing the editorDriver. This is a very common problem. If the editorDriver call to initialize doesn't have access to the subeditor (cannot see it) it will not be flushed when you flush the editorDriver.

Comment: It's just in a Presenter/View in the same package as the editors. I don't think it's an issue of being able to see it - think it should see it once it gets attached to the chain, that's the problem. Possibly, I can't edit the same entity with the parent editor and the child editor at the same time, so I need to create a wrapper for the dropdown box... might try that.

Comment: I do the same thing for handling different kinds of ad entities but as @colin-alworth mentioned I use the ValueAwareEditor in an abstract class. You do have to handle flush and set but this is a small tradeoff for simplicity of being able to dynamically add an editor.

Comment: I  would have implemented something like LeafValueEditor<Commission> and  HasSelectionHandlers<Commission> with its corresponding getValue and setValue implementation.

Comment: I have done it another way guys, and would appreciate the feedback if you'd like to contribute :)

Answer (score 2):

Your composite editor is declared as `CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, Editor<Commission>>`, which means that the chain will be expected to provide some arbitrary `Editor<Commission>`. This is a problem, since the compiler inspects the type `Editor<Commission>` and sees no sub-editors, and no other editor interfaces (`LeafValueEditor`, `ValueAwareEditor`, etc), so binds nothing to it.

You mention that you have two different `Editor<Commission>` subtypes - but the codegenerator can't know this ahead of time, and it wouldn't make sense to inspect every possible subtype and build any possible wiring that could fit. For better or worse, the editor framework is intended to be static - declare everything up-front, and then the generator will create only exactly what is needed.

Two options that I see:

- either create two different CompositeEditors, one for each sub-editor type, and just make sure you only attach one at a time, or
- extract a common supertype/interface from both editors, that have consistently named and typed methods which return the same editor types (never returning simply `Editor<Foo>` for the same reason as above). This likely will be harder to do, but its possible that you could wrap things up with `ValueAwareEditor` and use `setValue` and `flush()` to paper over the details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I declared `CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, Editor<Commission>>` because I was copying the other question that had `CompositeEditor<QuestionDataProxy, QuestionDataProxy, Editor<QuestionDataProxy>>` but I guess that explains why he says his `flush()` method doesn't work. If I change the `IsCommissionEditor` interface into a base class and then declare `CompositeEditor<Commission, Commission, BaseCommissionEditorWidget>` should that work? I'll try...

Comment: When you do try if there are more issues, update the question (perhaps under a `----`), with the body of the `BaseCommissionEditorWidget` and any subclasses.

Comment: I did try to make all of my subtypes implement a `BaseCommissionEditorWidget` but I was still getting the same issues attaching to the chain for some reason. However, your explanation of the code generator needing a concrete class made me realise I could do the logic inside a new concrete class (`CommissionSubtypeEditor`) ... I have posted my solution above and hope it's not too verbose / clunky. Well, it is GWT after all ;))) Thanks a ton as always, Colin.